# Property Grid Decimal Focus (DenisVuyka version)

Tags: .net, wpf, focus, propertygrid

I am using WPF Property Grid by Denis Vuyka https://github.com/DenisVuyka/WPG

I am having an issue where if i use Validation TextBox, and a number range, when i clear out the text box, and want to enter "0.2" but type in the order of

"." => "2" , then it becomes "0.2" BUT, the focus is here "0.|2", it is driving me nuts and i cannot figure it out.

If anyone has this problem or have faced this problem, it would great if you guys can help me out.

Thanks and Regards,
Kev

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen or worked with with the code you provided in your link, but it sounds like a known issue with TextBoxes that try and apply formatting while you're editing them.

Usually I recommend removing formatting from the TextBox while editing it, and only applying the formatting when it's not being edited

```
<Style x:Key="NumberFormatTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue, StringFormat=N2}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```